# How to force Event Trace Session to flush data more often?

Tags: windows, wmi, etw

I have a driver that writes alot of trace logs using WPP.

I have configured an [AutoLogger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) registry key entry to write the events to an .etl file.

The logging session is started successfully and the file is created, but it appears that the data is flushed to disk once in a long while. 
Is it possible to make it flush data more often or even in real time?

I tried playing with the "Flush Timer" but based on what is written in MSDN and on the effect it had it is not what I am looking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like an error in the documentation, in all other places where you configure the FlushTimer you will get what you want: the events in your buffer flushed to your session (no matter if real-time or file). I think that you somehow missed something in your test while trying it.

Comment: It doesn't still seem to write the buffer with each new message. I guess it depends on the buffer sizes (buffers are flushed only when they get full).

Answer (score 0):

You can force the buffer to be flushed using [ControlTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363696(v=vs.85).aspx) using the `EVENT_TRACE_CONTROL_FLUSH` control code.